# FBreader integration in a new app

Tags: android, user-interface, ebook-reader

I've downloaded the source code of [FBreader](https://github.com/geometer/FBReaderJ) for android and now I want to integrate this inside another android app.

Now, what would be the way to integrate an app with another?

- use it as a plugin?
- or use an API?

I'm new to android and haven't dealt with this much big code.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You must start with FBMain java file only and use other when required.

Comment: yeah well i am doing that only but i wanted to know that how can i remove the functions or java files which are useless to me.

Comment: FBMain doesn't exist in FBReader. You should begin from FBReader.java file.